# make random edges for a graph using java.util

Tags: java

This code creates a graph with random vertices. I want to make random edges for it. When removing the /* */ signs in the code, it sometimes compiles well, it sometimes doesn't, but I can't figure out why. 
More overly, the commented lines still don't do what I want: to create random edges, given the number of vertices.

Maybe someone could suggest what would be the way for implementing my idea, or at least, explain or give a fix for the commented code?

Thanks, if you answer.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Random;

class Graph{
    class Edge{
        int v;
        public Edge(int v){
            this.v=v;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString(){
            return "("+v+")";
        }
    }
    List<Edge> G[];
    public Graph(int n){
        G=new LinkedList[n];
        for(int i=0;i<G.length;i++)
            G[i]=new LinkedList<Edge>();
    }

    void addEdge(int u,int v){
        G[u].add(0,new Edge(v)); 
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        String result="";
        for(int i=0;i<G.length;i++)
            result+=i+"=>"+G[i]+"\n";
        return result;
    }
}

public class Graph01 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

      int numero = (int) (Math.random() * 5) + 5;
      int numero1 = (int) (Math.random() * 5) + 5;
      int numero2 = (int) (Math.random() * 5) + 5;

      Graph g = new Graph(numero);

     /*  g.addEdge(numero1, numero2 );  
         g.addEdge(numero1, numero2 ); */

        System.out.println(g);                  
    }
}
```

Comment: You should give more details, do you want the graph to end up being connected , or it doesn't matter?

Comment: it doesn't matter

Comment: Its like: g.addEdge(0, 2 ); adds an edge to the graph, independently of the number of vertices. So a first idea for creating an edge in a random vertex, would be writing something like g.addEdge(numero1, numero2 ); , and if that worked, maybe I can try and code something random which chooses to add several random edges, a random subgraph of  the complete graph of the given n vertices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, code is preparing an array of size 'N': suppose n is **8**.

```
public Graph(int n) {
    G = new LinkedList[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < G.length; i++)
        G[i] = new LinkedList<Edge>();
}
```

Secondly, code is adding value in array G[u] where suppose 'u' is **9**, like below

```
void addEdge(int u, int v) {
    G[u].add(0, new Edge(v));
}
```

So in this case definitely it will fail and throw **java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException**.

**Solution:**
I think you should write a code like that, `numero` field value must be greater than `numero1`.